# Draggable image with link-areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I know that I can make an image draggable by using `$('#id').draggable();`
But if the image contains some link-areas, these areas can't be used for dragging. Is there a way to tell jQuery to differ between a click (the defined url for this area should be opend) and a drag (simply move the whole image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve my goal.
The code for the image and the areas has to lay inside a div:

```
<div id="overlayDiv">
    <img id="overlayImage" src="/Content/images/Overlay.png" usemap="#overlayMap" />
    <map name="overlayMap" id="overlayMap">
        [some areas]
    </map>
</div>
```

Then you can make the div draggable:

```
var stopPropagation = false;
$('body').mouseup(function () { stopPropagation = false; });
$('#overlayDiv').draggable({
    stop: function () {
        stopPropagation = true;
    }
});
```

Because my areas don't have urls defined but only onclick-events, I'm able to check the stopPropagation variable and decide whether to ignore the click or not.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an option where you can prevent elements inside #id to be draggable: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

Apply this to your link elements and they will be clickable.

```
$("#id" ).draggable({ cancel: "a" });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's just the other way around: I want to be able to start dragging from the areas, but they should stay clickable as well

Comment: Then you probably need your own custom dragging functionality, which is not hard to make though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, and also wouldnt be prefereable from a UI point of you. You have no way to tell that a user has clicked on the link to 'open it' OR 'drag it'.

So trying to change the default behaviour of the click event on the link my confuse the user which is not good for User Experience.